# Question categories

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Would it be possible to rank and then sort questions on a scale of easy, intermediate, and complex? It would help if there was some definitive system that would be used for ranking questions (perhaps including: external sources; multiple opinions; controversial questions; high risk of issur involved; etc.)

Comment: Addition- maybe also changes level of difficulty depending on the number of answers that are helpful or unhelpful.

Comment: The purpose would be for users to be able to choose which level question they want to try to answer, etc.

Comment: I can't imagine how this would be done automatically. If you want to do it manually and post a list, go ahead.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: I can't imagine how this would be done automatically either, but there are so many wonderful things here that were programmed to be done automatically, and I was hoping the geniuses behind the many wonderful brilliant bits on this site could figure out a way to do this...

Answer (score 4):

In *theory*, this is possible on very technical sites, backed by some kind of complex machine learning. A system *could* learn that questions about .. let's say ... regular expressions are inherently harder than questions about array indexes. That would be interesting, actually *really* interesting, but the pay off for the amount of research and work that it would take wouldn't really justify the cost. That's not to diminish the actual usefulness of such a feature, it's just not capable of justifying the immense cost of developer time to pull it off.

If this were to happen, we'd almost have to stumble on it accidentally, while trying to do something else related to our tag prediction and other systems that help put stuff that interests you in your feed and on the front page.

This *could* be done using tags, but you'd be getting pretty heavy into [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) territory, something I'd strongly advise against.

Declining this not because it's uninteresting or not useful, but at this point, it's not really something we'd be able to take on.

Comment: Wow. Very cool. I understand why it isn't worth the time and effort.